# concatenate string to form dynamic xml string in python

Tags: python

I have a list contains strings and its length is variable.

```
mylist=["str1","str2","str3"]
```

I need to make a xml string using this list like

```
mystring="<mytag>str1</mytag><mytag>str2</mytag><mytag>str3</mytag>"
```

How do i make this kind of dynamic xml string from the list?

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist=["str1","str2","str3"]

print( "".join('<mytag>{}</mytag>'.format(x) for x in mylist) )
```

If you need something more complex then you should use `lxml`, `Beautifull`, etc.

Comment: it works for me  - do you get error message or what ?

Comment: it prints as str122str2str3

Comment: mypython version is 2.7

Comment: where do you print it - in console or in web browser ? Web browser doesn't display tags.

Comment: sorry i just checked in the browser.now its working.thankyou

Comment: I checked it in Python 2.7 and 3.5 and it display correctly in console/terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134346/discussion-between-akhilviswam-and-furas).